# Time to remove the TeX and LaTeX tags from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, migration

I was reviewing this question for closure

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682021/good-example-for-float-command-in-latex

Setting aside the fact that the question itself is pretty insipid and ought to be closed for insufficient prior research, isn't it time to remove the TeX and LaTeX tags from Stack Overflow in order to encourage such questions to be asked on the more appropriate Stack Exchange site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/?

I imagine that questions tagged solely as TeX and LaTeX could be moved automatically.

Comment: A couple of SE sites have some overlap with each other, like some question are equally valid on both Programmers.SE and PM.SE. I think same is the case here. I don't think TeX and LaTeX tags should be removed from SO.

Comment: *At most*, I'd say a little text/tip informing the users that their question might be suitable on another specific site(based on tags). Even then it would be pretty tricky to get them all "right". *Definitely* not "move automatically".

Comment: @GenericHolidayName how about we use the tag wiki for what you are proposing?

Answer (score 6):

There are a significant number of [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) questions on Stack Overflow that predate the TeX/LaTeX site and won't be migrated.  I don't think we can get rid of the tags, or we'd be making those questions and answers a lot harder to find.